# How to successfully use data-wrapperels="div"

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, html

I read somewhere that the `data-wrapperels` is offered by `JQM` to allow developpers to choose the container generated for a hierarchy.  I cannot find this reference anymore, nor can I find any specific documentation on this attribute.

I use the `data-wrapperels` to request JQM to use div instean of span, however, JQM overwrites this specification and reset to "span".

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards.

Here is the code:

```
<a id="myhomebutton" 
   href="index.html" 
   data-iconpos="notext" 
   data-wrapperels="div" 
   data-corners="false" 
   data-role="button"></a>
```

And here is what I am ending with (after JQM has process its chemistry):

```
<a id="myhomebutton" 
   href="index.html" 
   data-iconpos="notext" 
   data-corners="false" 
   data-role="button" 
   class="ui-btn-left..." 
   data-shadow="true" 
   data-iconshadow="true" 
   data-wrapperels="span" 
   data-theme="a" title="">

   <span class="ui-btn-inner">

      <span class="ui-btn-text"></span>

   </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Maybe *somebody* used `data-wrapperels` to choose a container. Do you see that attribute on any of your containers?

Comment: @lbstr: Unfortunuatly no, I chose data-wrapperels="div" and none of the childrens are of that type.

Comment: what happens if you just try to select `$('[data-wrapperels]')`? I'm just curious if there are any elements on the page with that attribute at all. Your selector would not only require that that attribute be there, but that it have a value of "div".

Comment: Thank you for your edit; that help clear up my confusion. I know I've seen taht attribute, but I can't find any documentation on it. Are you aware of any?

Comment: data-wrapperels does exist has it is added by JQM even if I do not specify my "div" specification.

Comment: I have the same problem on google search, nothing on jqm website.

Comment: Strange... Well, can you explain what you expect it to do? Maybe we can just do it ourselves. You're expecting it to wrap your anchor in a div?